# How do you calculate a negative binomial regression model in Python just like R?

Tags: python, r, model

In the output of the following code in R

```
data = read.csv("Data/From Ezra Haur chapter 8 poisson likelihood fit.csv")

nb_model <- glm.nb(Accidents ~ Miles, data = data)
summary(nb_model) 


'
Deviance Residuals: 
  Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.7790  -1.0475  -0.9460   0.1481   4.0601  

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.38006    0.02881  -13.19   <2e-16 ***
  Miles        0.55827    0.01350   41.35   <2e-16 ***
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.5487) family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 6202.1  on 5322  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4823.4  on 5321  degrees of freedom
AIC: 16741

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


Theta:  0.5487 
Std. Err.:  0.0182 

2 x log-likelihood:  -16734.6290
```

I'm trying to get the same data in Python and the results are close but not exactly the same.
The code in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy.stats import chi2

df = pd.read_csv('From Ezra Haur chapter 8 poisson likelihood fit.csv')

# Fit negative binomial regression model
model_nb = sm.GLM(df['Accidents'], sm.add_constant(df['Miles']), family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial())
result = model_nb.fit()

# Display summary
print(result.summary())

                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:              Accidents   No. Observations:                 5323
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                     5321
Model Family:        NegativeBinomial   Df Model:                            1
Link Function:                    Log   Scale:                          1.0000
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                -8524.2
Date:                Mon, 08 Jan 2024   Deviance:                       6528.4
Time:                        19:48:28   Pearson chi2:                 9.87e+03
No. Iterations:                    19   Pseudo R-squ. (CS):             0.3214
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         -0.3278      0.024    -13.797      0.000      -0.374      -0.281
Miles          0.5251      0.010     50.668      0.000       0.505       0.545
==============================================================================

# Scale dispersion parameter for comparison with R
scaled_dispersion_parameter = dispersion_parameter / result.family.variance(1.0)

# Display results
print(f"Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial({scaled_dispersion_parameter:.4f}) family taken to be 1")

>>> Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.5000) family taken to be 1
```

Is there a way to calculate it so that I get the same coefficients for the model and the dispersion parameter?

I tried to get the same coefficients for the model and the dispersion parameter